# How to display data from Mongodb in React using Axios

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, axios, mern

I'm facing difficulty displaying data in React - Here is my code:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';


export default function ProductCatalog() {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    function addProduct() {
            navigate('/adding')
    }

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([{}])
    
    useEffect(() => {

        const axiosProd = async () => {
            const response = await Axios('http://localhost:3001/getProducts');
            setProducts(response.data)
        };
        axiosProd();
    }, []);

                const useProducts = products.map((product)=>{
                    return <div>
                            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                        </div>
                })

                return(
                    <>
                    <button className = "button" onClick={addProduct}>Add New Product</button>
                    <br></br>
                    {useProducts}
                    </>
                )
}
```

I know data is coming in as JSON Objects as when i follow the link of http://localhost:3001/getProducts, I see my data. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function then outside of the function call the use effect.
To do a get request using axios use `axios.get(api)`

For example:

```
// Get All Shoes
const getShoes = () => {
      axios.get('/shoes')
        .then(res => setShoes(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

Then

```
useEffect(() => {
   getShoes();
}, [])
```